# php memory limit vs number of clients

Tags: php, memory

I am working with a large array that will require 256MB of ram to operate.  When I increase my memory on PHP, how does this effect my system as a whole when handling multiple clients?  Does the PHP service just eat up 256 MB or would it be 256 * # of clients?  If that is the case, is it creating the space in ram and then removing it when done, I assume for a fraction of a second.

Comment: What are you doing that requires 256 MB of RAM?

Comment: What's in this array? If it's just linear data, you should consider using a database or some other filing system to store it, instead of forcing PHP to load/parse 256meg worth of data every time the script fires up. And if the on-disk size is 256meg, remember that PHP has to allocate metadata for every element of that array, so you'll end up needing MORE than 256meg to store that 256meg in memory within php.

Answer (score 2):

For each client your php script will consume 256Mb, so it be 256 * # of clients

Comment: For curiosity: Will those 256MB be blocked as a whole as soon as the script starts, or allocated on demand? In other words, if I set max memory to 256MB per script on a machine with 1GB of RAM, will the RAM definitely be exhausted with 5 users connected at the same, or does this depend on the actual usage?

Comment: Memory isn't consumed until you create objects that use it. Max memory is just a limit, it doesn't reserve it immediately.

Comment: memory_limit php.ini setting configure maximum consumption, allocation is done on demand, so if other scripts do not allocate it - don't worry, but if all clients will use the same script simultaneously and this script will allocate 256M - yeap, you will have troubles with virtual memory